# Classic ASP - Server.CreateObject Failed Error

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am very new to classic ASP. I wrote a little piece of code in it. That is:

```
Dim Upload: Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
Server.CreateObject Failed
/UploadScript.asp, line 4
800401f3
```

P.S. I found some solutions on StackOverFlow asking to register dll etc. But I'm using no dll.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to register the `Persits` library. Do you have it?

Comment: Then you need to get it and register it. You can't use a library if you don't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the ASPUpload component.  You can get it here:

http://www.aspupload.com/